# Tomcat not getting started

Tags: tomcat

I am following https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04 link to install tomcat on ubuntu 14.04 instance.
when I do a

```
sudo initctl reload-configuration
sudo initctl start tomcat
```

it says starting/running but when I do a `service tomcat status` it says `stop/waiting` . There are no logs getting generated in the logs directory. Not sure why. logs directory permissions are `drwxr_xr_x`.

Comment: Change the permission to 777 so everybody can write in it and test again

Comment: still the same.

Comment: `getent group tomcat` gives `tomcat:x:1001:` I think the issue is with 1001. How to change this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install tomcat is not from repositories . First make sure you have java version installed . Go to fallowing link [tomcat 8.5 and 8.0 download page](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi) 
and click on readme link for whichever version of tomcat you wish to install . There you will find java version recommended.If you have latest version of java than the one specified in there that's fine because java is backward compatible otherwise .  Download java SE from oracle download (as it is more stable)and set the classpath in .bashrc and .profile_rc files in your home directory 
for example like this

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/mahiti/Desktop/jdk8/
export PATH=$PATH:<path to the bin directory in your java extracted directory>
```

the path should be absolute path as shown in assignment of JAVA_HOME above

These lines should be last line in your .bashrc file. If you don't have .profile_rc file create new one .

download the `.tar.gz` version of core binary distribution of the tomcat you want and extract it to folder . This folder generally will be /opt .
now open a new terminal and use `cd` command to change to the bin directory of where you have extracted tomcat . Then you will be able to start tomcat which fallowing command

```
sh startup.sh
```

note that i give JAVA_HOME as `/home/mahiti/Desktop/jdk8/`
and in PATH i give `/home/mahiti/Desktop/jdk8/bin` for specifing java